# node js MODULE_NOT_FOUND error in node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

I am new to javascript and I am having import issues.

I  have installed the `jquery.csv` lib as `npm i jquery.csv` but then node is not able to import it.  (this was the procedure described in https://github.com/typeiii/jquery-csv)

Here is the structure of my project:

```
lucapuggini@lucas-MBP js_utils % ls
index.js                index.js~               node_modules            package-lock.json       package.json
lucapuggini@lucas-MBP js_utils % ls node_modules 
jquery-csv
lucapuggini@lucas-MBP js_utils % cat index.js

var csv = require('./jquery.csv.js');

console.log("Start index.js")
lucapuggini@lucas-MBP js_utils % cat package-lock.json 
{
  "name": "js_utils",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "requires": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery-csv": {
      "version": "1.0.11",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery-csv/-/jquery-csv-1.0.11.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-KDPc3wFLTFO68p/4IqsODZCjBp+y9axDa/pr36pDKrWk6yyHf8Nk1FqAGXvaUb6H7J1zJSYszABIFj0a40QXRA=="
    }
  }
}
lucapuggini@lucas-MBP js_utils % node index.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './jquery.csv.js'
Require stack:
- /Users/lucapuggini/ProgrammingProjects/padel/trunk/js_utils/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:763:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:991:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/lucapuggini/ProgrammingProjects/padel/trunk/js_utils/index.js:2:11)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1102:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1131:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:807:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/lucapuggini/ProgrammingProjects/padel/trunk/js_utils/index.js'
  ]
}
lucapuggini@lucas-MBP js_utils %
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: simple - you try to load file that not exists.

Comment: but on the github page they say: `var csv = require('./jquery.csv.js');` ?  Is it an error in the doc?

Comment: Have you tried to import it like this? `const csv = require('jquery-csv');`

Comment: I think it's a bug in the package/documentation.

Comment: I tried both `csv = require('jquery.csv'); ` and `csv = require('./jquery.csv'); ` same error

Comment: sorry this works: `const csv = require('jquery-csv');`

Comment: @Donbeo report the bug to the package creators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems their documentation is incorrect. You need to `require` the npm module like this:

```
const csv = require('jquery-csv');
```

Comment: when I added this line and do "npm install jquery-csv", there's still error saying there's no declaration, can you please advise on what to do?